# How do I configure a connection to my Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server without username or password?

Tags: asp.net, postgresql, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I want to configure an access to my Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server without username or password, I found a similar solution for SqlServer which looks like this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            var credential = new DefaultCredential();
            var token = credential.GetToken(
                new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://databaes.windows.net/.default" }));
            sqlConnection.AccessToken = token.Token;
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(sqlConnection);
        }
```

Can I transform this code for PostgreSQL? Now I am registering my Db like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<MediaContext>(opt =>
            {
                opt.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString(MediaContext.DbConnectionName));
            });
```

I need a code or an explanation of how to connect to the database in my asp.net core web api using entity framework, preferable detailed as I am new to the azure.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to configure your PostgreSQL database to allow azure AD authentication:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-configure-sign-in-azure-ad-authentication

Then you connect to the database using the managed identity of your service

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-connect-with-managed-identity

Code example is in the link. You also need to grant the managed identity of your service access to the database,